# Displaying data in front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I have api end point which return a comments by id,  get/comments/:id,
when I test it in postman I get the following result:

```
{
    "id": 401478,
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "author": "Gimly",
            "content": "There is some decent fun to be found in _Beyond Anarchy_. It's more _Escape from LA_ than it is _Death Race 2000_, but still an entry in the franchise, which brings me to the core problem of Beyond Anarchy: Is it even really a _Death Race_ movie? The answer is yes, but to go beyond that an ask: Should it have been a _Death Race_ movie? The answer's probably no.\r\n\r\nAs I said to begin with, I had some fun with the movie, but the things that kept bringing it down were its awkward, half-hearted attatchments to the movies in the series that had gone before it. If they had have abandoned those sentiments completely, it probably would have made a better viewing experience, but then, if that had been the case, how could you call it _Death Race 4_? The opposite approach probably would have worked too, having Beyond Anarchy be an actual sequel that follows _Death Race 3_ and what came before in a way that makes sense, but then, it couldn't have been even close to the movie that we got.\r\n\r\nInstead we have _Beyond Anarchy's_ sequel-limbo status, a movie that I don't regret watching, but that also can't really work for people who are fans of the _Death Race_ franchise, or for people who have never even seen a Death Race movie.\r\n\r\n_Final rating:★★½ - Had a lot that appealed to me, didn’t quite work as a whole._",
            "id": "5af426b50e0a2639430091df",
            "url": "https://www.themoviedb.org/review/5af426b50e0a2639430091df"
        }
    ],
    "total_pages": 1,
    "total_results": 1
}
```

I want this resust to be displayed in front end, here is what I have done
 Here is component.ts

```
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private moviesService: MoviesService) {
    this.movie = [];
    this.review = [];
  }

        ngOnInit() {
                this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
                  // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
                  let id = params['id'];
                  this.moviesService.getReview(id)
                   .then(review => {
                     console.log(review);
                    this.review = review;
                  });
                });
              }
         }
```

Here is service.ts

```
export class MoviesService {

  reviewUrl = '/comments/';
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000';
  constructor(private http: Http, private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }

  getReview(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + this.reviewUrl + id)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleData(res: any) {
    const body = res.json();
    console.log(body); // for development purposes only
    return body.result || body || {};
  }
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for development purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

In component html here is what I have:

```
 <div>
    <h1> Comments: {{review.content}} </h1>
    </div>
```

console.log(review) display the following result in browser:

```
{id: 401478, page: 1, results: Array(1), total_pages: 1, total_results: 1}
id
:
401478
page
:
1
results
:
Array(1)
0
:
{author: "Gimly", content: "There is some decent fun to be found in _Beyond An…at appealed to me, didn’t quite work as a whole._", id: "5af426b50e0a2639430091df", url: "https://www.themoviedb.org/review/5af426b50e0a2639430091df"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
total_pages
:
1
total_results
:
1
```

when I run the app comment section is blank, nothing displayed

```
comment:
```

what is wrong with my code? any help or suggestion what I need to change will be helpfully

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(review)` where did you put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response contains a array of **`result`**, you need to access like,

```
 <h1> Comments: {{review.results[0].content}} </h1>
```

if you want to display all the content, then you need to use ngFor,

```
<div *ngFor="let review of review.results" >
    <h1> Comments: {{review.content}} </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro el perfecto

Comment: did you check that post issue?

Comment: i have another thread can you check? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900485/data-are-not-saved-in-database

Answer (score 0):

```
{id: 401478, page: 1, results: Array(1), total_pages: 1, total_results: 1}
```

Your review does not have property **content**, you probably want to access `review.results[0].content`