# Variable scope React native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Hi everyone i'm working on a project where i get data from an arduino using websocket and change the display based on the data true (show green circles) else (show red circles), I tried too many things but it seems that the value that stored Variables (temp and val) they stay withing the scope of the function socket.on(Led_1) even though they are global variables and i'm losing my mind here.Images[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbhvP.jpg) / [APP VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTaim.jpg)

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Image} from 'react-native';
import {Icon,Header} from 'react-native-elements';
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('http://41.251.107.235/');
var val;
var temp;
export default class VuePrincipale extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={
            value: false,
            color: '#ff0000',
            Temperature: 50
        };
        socket.on('Led_1',function(data){
          val = data.message;
          if(val){
            temp = 10;
          }else{
            temp = 0;
          }
          console.log(temp);
          console.log(val);
        });
    }

    displayState_Led1(){
        if(temp)
        {
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#0cfc84'/>);
        }
        else{
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#f26a6a'/>);
        }
      }
      displayState_Led2(){
        if(temp)
        {
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#0cfc84'/>);
        }
        else{
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#f26a6a'/>);
        }
      };
      displayState_Led3(){
        if(temp)
        {
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#0cfc84'/>);
          console.log('TRUE FROM IF')
        }
        else{
          return(<Icon reverse type='ionicon' color='#f26a6a'/>);
        }
      }
```

Comment: So the values most likely are updating, I see nowhere in your code that would trigger a re-render.... Presumably you want to be calling `setState({ Temperature: temp })` at some point.

Comment: @James can you check this one too ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900485/data-are-not-saved-in-database?noredirect=1#comment88800987_50900485

Comment: temp here doesn't refer to Temperature it's just a temporary variable, and yeah i tried setSate({temp: data.message}) it returns an error setState() is not a function.